# css animation is not working in boostrap card, vue rendering

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have build bootstrap cards which explains pricing in my project. I used colllapse for the half of the card when the screen size is equal to mobile width. In vanilla bootstrap animation is being done using collapsing class as expecting however after I converted my project into vue js, collapsing class totally not working. The project is full bootstrap and I have installed jquery plugin into vue.Here is sample of my codes.

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div class="prices">
           <div class="container">
              <h1 class="comfortHeader" id="comfortHeader" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Наши цены</h1>
              <div class="d-flex row no-gutters justify-content-center">
                 <div class="card text-center mt-3" v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="i" id="body-collapsed">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">10 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 600 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 16 000тг </p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse mt-5">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="'#collapseOne'+i"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseOne"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom"></span>
                       </a> 
                       <div id="collapseOne"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed">
                          <transition-group name="list">
                             <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="j">
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price1}}</p>
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price2}}</p>
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;" >{{subItem.price3}}</p>
                             </div>
                          </transition-group>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div  v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="'k'+i" class="card text-center mt-3" id="body-collapsed2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5  class="card-title" >30 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title d-inline-block" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 300<span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 39 000тг </p>
                       <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 9 000 тг</p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="`#collapseTwo+${i}`"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom fa-md"></span>
                       </a>
                       <div id="collapseTwo"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed2">
                          <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="'l'+j">
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price4}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph"  class="card-text">{{subItem.price5}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">{{subItem.price6}}</p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div  v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="'p'+i" class="card text-center mt-3" id="body-collapsed3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <div class="sale">
                          Лучший выбор!
                       </div>
                       <h5 class="card-title">60 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" style="color: #2FAFE5;font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;" class="card-title">1 000 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 60 000тг</p>
                       <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 16 000 тг</p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="`#collapseThree+${i}`"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseThree"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-bottom"></span>
                       </a>
                       <div id="collapseThree"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed3">
                          <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="'k'+j">
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price7}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph"  class="card-text">{{subItem.price8}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price9}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">{{subItem.price10}}
        </p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
   import $ from 'jquery'
   export default {
     data(){
   return{
     pricing: [{
            name: 'price1',
             expand: false,
              items: [{
          id:1,
          price1:"10 онлайн уроков",
          price2:"Интерактивные задания",
          price3:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам",
                 price4:"30 онлайн уроков",
          price5:"Интерактивные задания",
          price6:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам",
             price7:"60 онлайн уроков",
          price8:"Премиальная поддержка",
          price9:"Обратная связ",
          price10:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам"
               },
   
   
             ]
   
             }
   
         ],
   }
   }
   methods: {
       navItemCollapse(index) {
         this.pricing = this.pricing.map((item, i) => {
           item.expand = !item.expand
           if (i !== index) {
             item.expand = false
           }
           return item
         })
       },
   
   
   
   },
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code in my development environment. I noticed that you did not close the `<template>` tag. Also after `data()` part in your script you must use `,` to separate it from methods.

After these modifications I added bootstrap and jQuery to my `main.js` file as follows:

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

`import 'jquery/src/jquery.js'`

`import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'`

I also commented the `<transition-group>` tag, because it shows me  a warning. For span tags that you used I simply replaced them with some texts. Here is my full Vue component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="prices">
           <div class="container">
              <h1 class="comfortHeader" id="comfortHeader" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">Наши цены</h1>
              <div class="d-flex row no-gutters justify-content-center">
                 <div class="card text-center mt-3" v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="i" id="body-collapsed">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5 class="card-title">10 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 600 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 16 000тг </p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse mt-5">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="'#collapseOne'+i"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseOne"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span>span1</span>
                       </a> 
                       <div id="collapseOne"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed">
                          <!-- <transition-group name="list"> -->
                             <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="j">
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price1}}</p>
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price2}}</p>
                                <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;" >{{subItem.price3}}</p>
                             </div>
                          <!-- </transition-group> -->
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div  v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="'k'+i" class="card text-center mt-3" id="body-collapsed2">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <h5  class="card-title" >30 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" class="card-title d-inline-block" style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;">1 300<span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 39 000тг </p>
                       <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 9 000 тг</p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="`#collapseTwo+${i}`"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseTwo"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span>span2</span>
                       </a>
                       <div id="collapseTwo"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed2">
                          <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="'l'+j">
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price4}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph"  class="card-text">{{subItem.price5}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">{{subItem.price6}}</p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div  v-for="(price,i) in pricing" :key="'p'+i" class="card text-center mt-3" id="body-collapsed3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                       <div class="sale">
                          Лучший выбор!
                       </div>
                       <h5 class="card-title">60 Уроков</h5>
                       <h5 id="biggerSize" style="color: #2FAFE5;font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:15px;" class="card-title">1 000 <span class="fas fa-tenge d-inline-block"></span></h5>
                       <p id="card-height" class="card-text">за урок</p>
                       <p class="card-text">Всего к оплате 60 000тг</p>
                       <p class="economyTariff">Сэкономить 16 000 тг</p>
                       <button class="SeeTheCourse">Начать заниматься</button>
                       <a class="collapsed d-lg-none d-md-block" 
                          data-toggle="collapse"
                          :data-target="`#collapseThree+${i}`"
                          aria-expanded="false"
                          aria-controls="collapseThree"
                          href="javascript:;"
                          @click.prevent="navItemCollapse(i)"
                          >
                       <span>span3</span>
                       </a>
                       <div id="collapseThree"  v-if="price.items.length>0" class="collapse d-lg-block" :class="{show: price.expand}" aria-labelledby="body-collapsed3">
                          <div v-for="(subItem,j) in price.items" :key="'k'+j">
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price7}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph"  class="card-text">{{subItem.price8}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text">{{subItem.price9}}</p>
                             <p id="lowerbodyparagraph" class="card-text" style="border-bottom: none;">{{subItem.price10}}
        </p>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            
</template>
    
    
<script>
   export default {
     data(){
   return{
     pricing: [{
            name: 'price1',
             expand: false,
              items: [{
          id:1,
          price1:"10 онлайн уроков",
          price2:"Интерактивные задания",
          price3:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам",
                 price4:"30 онлайн уроков",
          price5:"Интерактивные задания",
          price6:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам",
             price7:"60 онлайн уроков",
          price8:"Премиальная поддержка",
          price9:"Обратная связ",
          price10:"Безлимитный доступ к материалам"
               },
   
   
             ]
   
             }
   
         ],
   }
   },
   methods: {
       navItemCollapse(index) {
         this.pricing = this.pricing.map((item, i) => {
           item.expand = !item.expand
           if (i !== index) {
             item.expand = false
           }
           return item
         })
       },
   
   },
   }
</script>
```

It shows me the `a` tags in mobile resolution and collapse functionality also works. But there is no **animation** here. Maybe it comes from your CSS that is not included!